# How to Execute Stored Procedure with no select in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using about 10 stored procedures inside a cursor. While I run my sursor the sp's are executed and some sps contain select statement as well as DML operations too. I dont want that select statement to show. I want to execute only DML operations. That's enough. Is there any way ? 
     your Response is highly appreciated !

Comment: I think that's not possible...

Comment: If you don't need the SELECT - just don't put it in your stored proc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

The stored procedure is written to SELECT and return data. So it does.

Comment: Thanks for your Response.I used Stored Procedure not only for my cursor! It is used to perform the Insert or delete operations and the select is used to display results in UI. But i run this cursor to dynamically run the SP in Backend. So i dont want to display the results. i need to perform  only the DML Operations. The Problem is that, say for example, the cursor will run for 100 times and while on execution , the select shows more than 10000 rows. So the performance issue goes on there. Hence to optimize the Query Execution i need to stop the select statement. Is that Possible ?

Comment: No, you can't stop this unless you change you code or use different code. It is that simple. Split the stored proc into update and select?